# Elasticsearch: Exclude non-matching nested objects in results

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch, is there any way to exclude the nested objects that don't match a particular query/filter from the resulting _source?

For example, let's say that a document has four objects in a nested field. Querying on the required filters results in only matching objects 1 and 3. When we get the results via _source, we will pull back the entire document along with objects 1,2,3,4.

Is it possible to exclude objects 2 and 4 from the results? Or is that something that we have to re-iterate and exclude using application-side logic?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment there is no way to include only the matched nested objects in the result.

There is a [inner_hits](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-request-inner-hits.html) feature coming out in elasticsearch 1.5.0 which should help with this.

Comment: Great to hear. This is something I wanted to be able to do too, and couldn't find any way to do it currently.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with use of inner_hits which will return you only matching nested objects. you can exclude this nested field in source.


Suggested by Val at:
[ElasticSearch - Get only matching nested objects with All Top level fields in search response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40779957/elasticsearch-get-only-matching-nested-objects-with-all-top-level-fields-in-se?noredirect=1#comment68783228_40779957)