# ElasticSearch - Filter nested objects without affecting the "parent" object

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl

I have an ElasticSearch mapping for a blog object that contains a nested field for comments. This is so a user can add comments to the blog content shown above. The comments field has a published flag that determines whether or not the comment can be viewed by other users or just by the main user.

```
"blogs" :[
{
     "id":1,
     "content":"This is my super cool blog post",
     "createTime":"2017-05-31",
      "comments" : [
            {"published":false, "comment":"You can see this!!","time":"2017-07-11"}
       ]
},
{
     "id":2,
     "content":"Hey Guys!",
     "createTime":"2013-05-30",
     "comments" : [
               {"published":true, "comment":"I like this post!","time":"2016-07-01"},
               {"published":false, "comment":"You should not be able to see this","time":"2017-10-31"}
       ]
},
{
     "id":3,
     "content":"This is a blog without any comments! You can still see me.",
     "createTime":"2017-12-21",
     "comments" : None
},
]
```

I want to be able to filter the comments so only True comments will be displayed for each blog object. I want to show every blog, not just those with true comments. All of the other solutions I have found online seem to affect my blog object. Is there a way to filter out the comment object without affecting the querying of all blogs?

So the above example would be returned after the query as such:

```
"blogs" :[
{
     "id":1,
     "content":"This is my super cool blog post",
     "createTime":"2017-05-31",
      "comments" : None # OR EMPTY LIST 
},
{
     "id":2,
     "content":"Hey Guys!",
     "createTime":"2013-05-30",
     "comments" : [
               {"published":true, "comment":"I like this post!","time":"2016-07-01"}
       ]
},
{
     "id":3,
     "content":"This is a blog without any comments! You can still see me.",
     "createTime":"2017-12-21",
     "comments" : None
},
]
```

The example still shows the blogs that have no comments or false comments.

Is this possible?

I have been using a nested query from this example: [ElasticSearch - Get only matching nested objects with All Top level fields in search response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40779957/elasticsearch-get-only-matching-nested-objects-with-all-top-level-fields-in-se?noredirect=1#comment68783228_40779957)

But this example affects the blogs themselves and will  not return blogs that have only false comments or no comments.

Please help :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so found out that there is apparently no way to do this using the elasticsearch queries. But I figured out a way to do this on the django/python side (which is what I needed). I'm not sure if anyone will need this information, but if you are in need of this and you are using Django/ES/REST this is what I did.

I followed the elasticsearch-dsl documentation (http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to connect elasticsearch with my Django app. Then I used the rest_framework_elasticsearch package framework for creating the views.

To create a Mixin that queries only the `True` nested attributes in the list of elasticsearch items, create a mixin subclass of the rest_framework_elastic.es_mixins ListElasticMixin object. Then overwrite the es_representation definition as follows in our new mixin.

```
class MyListElasticMixin(ListElasticMixin):
    @staticmethod
    def es_representation(iterable):

        items = ListElasticMixin.es_representation(iterable)

        for item in items:
            for key in item:
                if key == 'comments' and item[key] is not None:
                    for comment in reversed(item[key]):
                        if not comment['published']:
                            item[key].remove(comment)

        return items
```

Make sure that you use the `reversed` function in the for loop of comments or you will skip over some of your comments in the list.

This I use this new filter in my view.

```
class MyViewSet(MyListElasticMixin, viewsets.ViewSet):
   # Your view code here

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Doing it on the python side is definitely easier and worked.