# Write a query for Array of objects in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to write a query for the below input(array of objects).

```
"UserDetails": [                                    
     { "Name" : "Vanaraj", "Age" : "27", "country" : "India" },
     { "Name" : "Ranjit", "Age" : "26", "country" : "US" }
  ]
```

Name, Age, Country are three different fields, their type is text.
From the front end, input will come like the above combination of all three fields with the array.

I need to write a query with these three combinations and filter the records from the index based on the combination of all the three fields and their values. "UserDetails" is just a name which I mentioned three fields only present in the index.

Search the index with the combination of {"Name" : "Vanaraj", "Age" : "27", "country" : "India"}  and  { "Name" : "Ranjit", "Age" : "26", "country" : "US" } and output should come whatever match with these combination.

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40780938/4604579 (hint: you need to leverage `nested` objects)

Comment: You have to use nested query - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe you are looking for something like this.

It looks a bit wacky but it roughly translates to:
"Find me (Vanaraj, 27 years old, in India) or (Ranjit, who is 26 in US)"

```
# Setup a sample index with data
PUT /stackoverflowtest/_doc/1
{ "Name" : "Vanaraj", "Age" : "27", "country" : "India" }
PUT /stackoverflowtest/_doc/2
{ "Name" : "Ranjit", "Age" : "26", "country" : "US" }
PUT /stackoverflowtest/_doc/3
{ "Name" : "Joe", "Age" : "38", "country" : "US" }

# Query that returns Vanaraj / 27 / India or Ranjit / 26 / US
POST /stackoverflowtest/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "Name": "Vanaraj"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "Age": "27"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "country": "India"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "Name": "Ranjit"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "Age": "26"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "country": "US"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```