# how to get only particular elements from an array in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm very new to elastic search. I'm trying to get some particular elements from an array...

I created my index like below

```
PUT store
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "storeList": {"type": "nested"},
      "storeLocation": {"type": "text"},
      "storePinCode" : {"type": "long"}
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm having data like this

```
{
    "storeLocation": "tirupati",
    "storePinCode" : 517501
    "storeList" : [
        {
            "storeName" : "apollo",
            "storeType" : "med"
        },
        {
            "storeName" : "carrots",
            "storeType" : "restaurants"
        },
        {
            "storeName" : "more",
            "storeType" : "supermarket"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "storeLocation": "hyderabad",
    "storePinCode" : 500038
    "storeList" : [
        {
            "storeName" : "apollo",
            "storeType" : "med"
        },
        {
            "storeName" : "bahar cafe",
            "storeType" : "restaurants"
        },
        {
            "storeName" : "dmart",
            "storeType" : "supermarket"
        }
    ]
}
```

**My excepted output** should be like below

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "store",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Yk8SFWwB2zt5weEsMHn7",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "storeLocation" : "tirupati",
          "storePinCode" : 517501,
          "storeList" : [
            {
              "storeName" : "apollo",
              "storeType" : "med"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "store",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ZE8SFWwB2zt5weEsqnkd",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "storeLocation" : "hyderabad",
          "storePinCode" : 500038,
          "storeList" : [
            {
              "storeName" : "apollo",
              "storeType" : "med"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

To achive that i try with below query

```
POST store/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "storeList",
      "query": {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {"match":{"storeList.storeName": "apollo"}}
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {} 
    }
  }
}
```

**I'm getting the output but it not exactly what I expect. Is it possible to get the output as I expect..?**

Actual Output:

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.093527,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "store",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Yk8SFWwB2zt5weEsMHn7",
        "_score" : 1.093527,
        "_source" : {
          "storeLocation" : "tirupati",
          "storePinCode" : 517501,
          "storeList" : [
            {
              "storeName" : "apollo",
              "storeType" : "med"
            },
            {
              "storeName" : "carrots",
              "storeType" : "restaurants"
            },
            {
              "storeName" : "more",
              "storeType" : "supermarket"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "storeList" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.093527,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "store",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "Yk8SFWwB2zt5weEsMHn7",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "storeList",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.093527,
                  "_source" : {
                    "storeName" : "apollo",
                    "storeType" : "med"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "store",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ZE8SFWwB2zt5weEsqnkd",
        "_score" : 1.093527,
        "_source" : {
          "storeLocation" : "hyderabad",
          "storePinCode" : 500038,
          "storeList" : [
            {
              "storeName" : "apollo",
              "storeType" : "med"
            },
            {
              "storeName" : "bahar cafe",
              "storeType" : "restaurants"
            },
            {
              "storeName" : "dmart",
              "storeType" : "supermarket"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "storeList" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.093527,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "store",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "ZE8SFWwB2zt5weEsqnkd",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "storeList",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.093527,
                  "_source" : {
                    "storeName" : "apollo",
                    "storeType" : "med"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

could you please help me out of this...

@ajay sharma, as you suggested i change my query like this

```
GET store/_search
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": [ "*" ],
    "excludes": [ "storeList" ]
  },
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "storeList",
      "inner_hits": {       
        "_source": [
          "storeName", "storeType"
        ]
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"match":{"storeList.storeName": "more"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but im getting the response like below...

```
{
        "_index" : "store",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Yk8SFWwB2zt5weEsMHn7",
        "_score" : 1.0946013,
        "_source" : {
          "storeLocation" : "tirupati",
          "storePinCode" : 517501
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "storeList" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0946013,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "store",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "Yk8SFWwB2zt5weEsMHn7",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "storeList",
                    "offset" : 2
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.0946013,
                  "_source" : { }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch - Get only matching nested objects with All Top level fields in search response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40779957/elasticsearch-get-only-matching-nested-objects-with-all-top-level-fields-in-se)

Comment: thx for your reply @AjaySharma, but I'm not getting output exactly. i updated my question can you please check it out

Answer (score 0):

I cannot respond to your comment by a comment. Therefore sharing as an answer.

I have updated the query below. Please check. I replicated your index on my local machine and could get the desired result.

**Query**

```
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": [ "*" ],
    "excludes": [ "storeList" ]
  },
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "storeList",
      "inner_hits": {       
        "_source": [
          "storeList.storeName", "storeList.storeType"  <-- changes are here -->
        ]
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"match":{"storeList.storeName": "more"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.9808292,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "store",
        "_type": "store",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.9808292,
        "_source": {
          "storeLocation": "tirupati",
          "storePinCode": 517501
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "storeList": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": 0.9808292,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "storeList",
                    "offset": 2
                  },
                  "_score": 0.9808292,
                  "_source": {
                    "storeList": {
                      "storeType": "supermarket",
                      "storeName": "more"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: nested elements are coming under 'inner_hits'. is it possible to get those nested elements along with top-level fields? could you please check expected output in my question for more details